# Redirect both stdout and stderr to output stream in Scala

Tags: scala, console, stdout, stderr, output-redirect

What I'd like to do in Scala is redirect both standard output and standard error to output streams. I am aware of `scala.Console.withOut` and `scala.Console.withErr` but it seems I need to call these functions separately, which leads to running my command (function) twice:

```
scala.Console.withOut(out)(f)
scala.Console.withErr(out)(f)
```

I'd like to call `f` only once and get both `out` and `err` in streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest them:

```
Console.withOut(out) {
  Console.withErr(out) {
    f
  }
}
```